# How to keep the header static, always on top while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I go about keeping my `header` from scrolling with the rest of the page? I thought about utilizing `frame-sets` and `iframes`, just wondering if there is a easier and more user friendly way, what would be the best-practice for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by `header`? Of a page? Of a table?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33075195/435605

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Note: This answer dates from 2010. Consider `position: sticky` in 2021, as mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58645785/1891625).

---

Use `position: fixed` on the `div` that contains your header, with something like

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

In this example, when `#content` starts off 100px below `#header`, but as the user scrolls, `#header` stays in place. Of course it goes without saying that you'll want to make sure `#header` has a background so that its content will actually be visible when the two `div`s overlap. Have a look at the `position` property here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position

Comment: depending on the relationship between your `div`s, you might need to add `margin-top: -100px;` to the `#header` to get it back where you want it.

Comment: Do you know of a way to let it scroll until it hits the top and then "position: fixed;"? If your header started below the top?

Comment: It is not contained within the DIV width for me.

Comment: This solution requires defining a hard-coded size. Is there a way doing it without a hard-coded size? Perhaps by defining one div to be below another? Perhaps some relationship between the header and content without hard-coded values?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Not really, no. Setting an element to be `position: fixed` effectively takes it out of the flow, which means that to other elements it no longer takes up any space. What you're looking for is [`position: sticky`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), which unfortunately does not have wide browser support yet

Comment: Never say never ;-) There's another way of doing this without using hard coded sizes - by playing with the scroll/overflow. See answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33076077/435605

Comment: `position: sticky` should be the accepted answer in 2021

Answer (score 72):

### `position: sticky;`

In [modern, supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), you can simply do that in CSS with -

```
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

In most case, it is better than using `position: fixed`, since `position: fixed` takes the element out of the regular flow of elements.

**Note**:

1. The HTML structure is important while using `position: sticky`, since it makes the element sticky relative to the parent. And the sticky positioning might not work with a single element made sticky within a parent.
2. The parent of the element made sticky should not have the `overflow` property set Eg: if parent has `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`, then sticky positioning might not work
3. Giving at least one of the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` is important because it makes the element sticky in relation to some position.

Run the snippet below to check a sample implementation.

```css
main {
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  padding:40px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

content > div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    This is my header
  </header>
  <content>
    <div>Some content 1</div>
    <div>Some content 2</div>
    <div>Some content 3</div>
    <div>Some content 4</div>
    <div>Some content 5</div>
    <div>Some content 6</div>
    <div>Some content 7</div>
    <div>Some content 8</div>
  </content>
</main>
```

Comment: If `position: sticky` does not work for you, I recommend https://university.webflow.com/lesson/create-a-sticky-sidebar which accurately pointed to my issue due to a parent's `overlow` setting

Answer (score 9):

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 88px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #eeeeee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.header__content-text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.page__content-container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 975px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="header__content-text">
    Header content will come here
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="page__content-container">
  <div style="height:600px;">
    <a href="http://imgur.com/k9hz3">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/k9hz3.jpg" title="Hosted by imgur.com" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:600px;">
    <a href="http://imgur.com/TXuFQ">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TXuFQ.jpg" title="Hosted by imgur.com" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can use bootstrap3 then you can use css "navbar-fixed-top"
also you need to add below css to push your page content down

```
body{

   margin-top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

here is one with css + jquery (javascript) solution.

here is demo link  [Demo](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/top-bar-opacity.php)

```
//html

<div id="uberbar">
    <a href="#top">Top of Page</a>
    <a href="#bottom">Bottom of Page</a>

</div>

//css 

#uberbar    { 
    border-bottom:1px solid #eb7429; 
    background:#fc9453; 
    padding:10px 20px; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:2000; 
    width:100%;
}

//jquery

$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        //settings
        var fadeSpeed = 200, fadeTo = 0.5, topDistance = 30;
        var topbarME = function() { $('#uberbar').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,1); }, topbarML = function() { $('#uberbar').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,fadeTo); };
        var inside = false;
        //do
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            position = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(position > topDistance && !inside) {
                //add events
                topbarML();
                $('#uberbar').bind('mouseenter',topbarME);
                $('#uberbar').bind('mouseleave',topbarML);
                inside = true;
            }
            else if (position < topDistance){
                topbarME();
                $('#uberbar').unbind('mouseenter',topbarME);
                $('#uberbar').unbind('mouseleave',topbarML);
                inside = false;
            }
        });
    })();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking through all the answers, I found a slightly different way with minimum CSS and no JS, only the height of the header needs to be set correctly in `#content`, in this case `60px`

CSS:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header" style="background-color:GRAY; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px SOLID BLACK; color:WHITE; line-height:50px; font-size:40px">
     My Large Static Header
  </div>
  <div id="content">
     <!-- All page content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with positioning and padding/margin and without knowing the header's size, there's a way to keep the header fixed by playing with the scroll.

See the [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E93RVzoWMHkXB1jXhpMw?p=preview) with a fixed header:

```
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%">
<div style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden">
  <div>Header</div>
  <div style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">Content - very long Content...
```

The key here is a mix of `height: 100%` with `overflow`.

See a specific question on removing the scroll from the header [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33075195/435605) and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33075567/435605).

Comment: A problematic solution. It seems that the bottom of the content is pushed below the window. You can see it more clearly if you make the header higher. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This seems to work fine but the scroll becomes very slow on my iPhone5.

Comment: @AlainZelink - What browser app are u using on an iPhone5?

Answer (score -9):

I personally needed a table with both the left and top headers visible at all times. Inspired by several articles, I think I have a good solution that you may find helpful. 
This version does not have the wrapping problem that other soltions have with floating divs or flexible/auto sizing of columns and rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        // Handler for scrolling events
        function scrollFixedHeaderTable() {
            var outerPanel = $("#_outerPanel");
            var cloneLeft = $("#_cloneLeft");
            var cloneTop = $("#_cloneTop");
            cloneLeft.css({ 'margin-top': -outerPanel.scrollTop() });
            cloneTop.css({ 'margin-left': -outerPanel.scrollLeft() });
        }

        function initFixedHeaderTable() {
            var outerPanel = $("#_outerPanel");
            var innerPanel = $("#_innerPanel");
            var clonePanel = $("#_clonePanel");
            var table = $("#_table");
            // We will clone the table 2 times: For the top rowq and the left column. 
            var cloneLeft = $("#_cloneLeft");
            var cloneTop = $("#_cloneTop");
            var cloneTop = $("#_cloneTopLeft");
            // Time to create the table clones
            cloneLeft = table.clone();
            cloneTop = table.clone();
            cloneTopLeft = table.clone();
            cloneLeft.attr('id', '_cloneLeft');
            cloneTop.attr('id', '_cloneTop');
            cloneTopLeft.attr('id', '_cloneTopLeft');
            cloneLeft.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                'pointer-events': 'none',
                top: outerPanel.offset().top,
                'z-index': 1 // keep lower than top-left below
            });
            cloneTop.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                'pointer-events': 'none',
                top: outerPanel.offset().top,
                'z-index': 1 // keep lower than top-left below
            });
            cloneTopLeft.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                'pointer-events': 'none',
                top: outerPanel.offset().top,
                'z-index': 2 // higher z-index than the left and top to make the top-left header cell logical
            });
            // Add the controls to the control-tree
            clonePanel.append(cloneLeft);
            clonePanel.append(cloneTop);
            clonePanel.append(cloneTopLeft);
            // Keep all hidden: We will make the individual header cells visible in a moment
            cloneLeft.css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
            cloneTop.css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
            cloneTopLeft.css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
            // Make the lef column header cells visible in the left clone
            $("#_cloneLeft td._hdr.__row").css({
                visibility: 'visible',
            });
            // Make the top row header cells visible in the top clone
            $("#_cloneTop td._hdr.__col").css({
                visibility: 'visible',
            });
            // Make the top-left cell visible in the top-left clone
            $("#_cloneTopLeft td._hdr.__col.__row").css({
                visibility: 'visible',
            });
            // Clipping. First get the inner width/height by measuring it (normal innerWidth did not work for me)
            var helperDiv = $('<div style="positions: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 100%;"></div>');
            outerPanel.append(helperDiv);
            var innerWidth = helperDiv.width();
            var innerHeight = helperDiv.height();
            helperDiv.remove(); // because we dont need it anymore, do we?
            // Make sure all the panels are clipped, or the clones will extend beyond them
            outerPanel.css({ clip: 'rect(0px,' + String(outerPanel.width()) + 'px,' + String(outerPanel.height()) + 'px,0px)' });
            // Clone panel clipping to prevent the clones from covering the outerPanel's scrollbars (this is why we use a separate div for this)
            clonePanel.css({ clip: 'rect(0px,' + String(innerWidth) + 'px,' + String(innerHeight) + 'px,0px)'   });
            // Subscribe the scrolling of the outer panel to our own handler function to move the clones as needed.
            $("#_outerPanel").scroll(scrollFixedHeaderTable);
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            initFixedHeaderTable();
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            clip: rect font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #_outerPanel {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 50px;
            right: 50px;
            bottom: 50px;
            overflow: auto;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        #_innerPanel {
            overflow: visible;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #_clonePanel {
            overflow: visible;
            position: fixed;
        }

        table {
        }

        td {
            white-space: nowrap;
            border-right: 1px solid #000;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        }

        td._hdr {
            color: Blue;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        td._hdr.__row {
            background-color: #eee;
            border-left: 1px solid #000;
        }
        td._hdr.__col {
            background-color: #ddd;
            border-top: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="_outerPanel">
        <div id="_innerPanel">
            <div id="_clonePanel"></div>
            <table id="_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead id="_topHeader" style="background-color: White;">
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="_hdr __col __row">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                        <td class="_hdr __col">
                            TOP HEADER
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="_hdr __row">
                            MY HEADER COLUMN:
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="_hdr __row">
                            MY HEADER COLUMN:
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                        <td class="col">
                            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="_bottomAnchor">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```