# How to make this navigation bar floating on top while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

The whole navigation bar along with its JavaScript settings can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/DyJzg/3/

right now it stays at the top of the page, but i am wonder whether it could be made floating on top even when you scroll down the page. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593594/how-to-keep-the-header-static-always-on-top-while-scrolling

Comment: unrelated but, if you click on the dropdown menu, and click again to close, after you leave the mouse the hover effect remains :O

Comment: @ajax333221 yep, never noticed that, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use `position:fixed`

```
nav {
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
}
```

here is [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyJzg/5/)

Comment: Thanks, actually I've tried this `postion:fixed` option before, but apparently something else in my css setting screwed it up. It works perfectly in the jsFiddle sandbox but not quite so in my actual pages. I need to figure it out but now I'm sure it's not the problem of the `nav` piece.

Answer (score 1):

if your element is 'nav' or your element class is '.nav' use this piece of css code:

```
nav, .nav{
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:your_custom_with;
height: your_custom_height
}
```

note: check this article of css positioning for more details:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: thanks, I checked that page, as I mentioned in my reply to @inrbob, something else screwed things up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, the following should do it..

```
.nav{
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   width:100%;
}
```