# conflict between floating navigation bar and floating div object on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

The whole setup is in the jsfiddle page here

http://jsfiddle.net/DyJzg/10/

The problem is that, the div block seems to conflict with the floating navigation bar so that the JavaScript dropdown does not work anymore.

This is a follow-up question of this old one:

[How to make this navigation bar floating on top while scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197298/how-to-make-this-navigation-bar-floating-on-top-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `z-index` to your `nav`, like so:

```
nav {position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;z-index:10}
```

Or, as an option, you can locate `<nav>` below `<div id="content">` in html code.