# How do I get my navigation bar to stay fixed like my favorite website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you take a look at gravitatedesign.com and you see the navigation bar is pink, and the letters are there, I want that bar to be there when I first load the page, not necessarily that color but I want it to be up there and to scroll with the page. How do I do this?

Comment: Tried anything? `position:fixed;`?

Comment: Have you tried position:fixed?
See this for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197298/how-to-make-this-navigation-bar-floating-on-top-while-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

This is called a sticky header. There are lots of tools that you can use to implement this but the easiest way is to just apply the following code to your header tag:

```
header { position: fixed; }
```

Comment: I just tried and it's not sticking to the top I like how it appears as I'm scrolling but it doesn't appear when I first load it.

Comment: Perhaps try adding an !important?

Answer (score 0):

For **Pink colored** bar, you should use

```
{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  height:40px;
}
```