# Header section always top on the web site

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep the header static, always on top while scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593594/how-to-keep-the-header-static-always-on-top-while-scrolling)

I want to keep the header section of the web site always on top while scrolling down the page.
how can i do with CSS ? or do I have to use Jquery ?

Comment: This is extremely simple -- use fixed positioning. Please see the question Juhana referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Ja3rp/)

Html IS:

```
<div id="header" class="fixed" style="display: block; top: 0px; ">
        <div class="inner">
        <!-- .inner -->
        </div>
        <div class="shadow" style="display:block;"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div style="height:600px;"><a href="http://imgur.com/k9hz3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/k9hz3.jpg" title="Hosted by imgur.com" alt="" /></a></div> 
<div style="height:600px;"><a href="http://imgur.com/TXuFQ"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TXuFQ.jpg" title="Hosted by imgur.com" alt="" /></a></div> ​
```

Css is:

```
 #header{height: 48px;width: 100%;z-index: 1000;}

.fixed {background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/njty47g/Omoleufdi/topbar_bg.png) left top repeat-x;
position: fixed;left: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
box-shadow: 0 7px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);}

.inner {width: 940px;margin: 0 auto;height: 48px;}


.shadow{width: 100%;height: 5px;position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: -5px;z-index: 500;display: none;}
​
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with CSS, this class will work for a div with the Id of "header":

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres the code explained:_

```
#header {
  position: fixed; /* keeps the element in a fixed position no matter how much you scroll */
  top: 0; /* to keep it on the top */
  width: 100%; /* to keep its width across the screen no matter how big the screen is */
  z-index: 1000; /* to make sure its infront of everything */
}
```

Its always good to keep your code commented so if you forget what something does, you can just look at the comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make your header 100% width then you can use

```
.headerDiv{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Position: fixed;`, will fix it to the window 
`Top:0;` will make sure it's up there,
`Left:0;` can be added to make sure it's left too,
`z-index:1000;` will make sure it stays above everything else on your page